# Updating pricing for all products

Tags: php, wordpress, import, google-sheets-formula, advanced-custom-fields

There is hundreds of products. They have all product names, URLs, etc in an excel sheet and are working on updating the pricing column. Is it possible to pull this data to update all the pages automatically, rather than one by one? Product is custompost and All other fileds are ACF Field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are ACF Fields but if you have some ID numbers like EAN's in your products database and the same EAN's (or other ID) which can be used to match them than it is sure this is possible. But you will have to write:
a) import code for eg .csv file with products and prices which will be used to update prices,
b) try to load data directly from google-sheets and use CRON to do it eg once a day, ofc. you will have to write this code or look for some WP addon (I don't know WP so i can't say if there is something for this).

So if you can match product from your DB to the product from your google sheet it's 100% sure you can do it automatically.

Comment: Its not woocommerce site. so there is no any unique identifier. Please provide an effective plugin

Comment: I cannot provide plugin since I am not interested in WP at all. :) I wrote I am not WP dev. Btw. I am curious why you chose Wp with ACF as a shop instance?